# Wildcard subdomain routing from WAN to LAN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, dnsmasq, ddns

**My current setup:**

- I don't have a static IP from my ISP, so I run my own ddns on a Google Cloud instance
- The ddns I'm running is a docker image from https://github.com/dprandzioch/docker-ddns, and I followed the instructions to configure the Google Cloud DNS
- The domain `foo.dyndns.domain.tld` successfully points to my public IP address
- At home, I have an Asus AC56U router with `dnsmasq` running on it.
- `dnsmasq` points all `local.dev` requests to my local webserver
- I've enabled port-forwarding for `port 80` to my web-server

**My dnsmasq configuration on my AC56U router**

```
address=/local.dev/foo.dyndns.domain.tld/192.168.1.100
```

**My DNS settings in Google Cloud DNS**

```
ns.domain.tld.             A       300   35.xx.xx.xx
dyndns.domain.tld          NS      300   ns.domain.tld
```

**What currently works:**

- All `*.local.dev` requests, successfully point to my webserver within my LAN network
- `foo.dyndns.domain.tld` successfully points to my webserver outside of my LAN `ping foo.dyndns.domain.tld` returns my public IP.

**What I need**

- `*.foo.dyndns.domain.tld` to point to my webserver outside of my LAN network `ping test.foo.dyndns.domain.tld` results in `Unknown host`
- I'd like it to happen automatically, so without updating NS records for every new project I start working on.

**What's the point?**

I'm a web- and mobile app developer, and I'd like to allow my clients to access my local dev-server. Unfortunately, my networking experiences are very limited.

**What I tried so far**

I tried updating my Google Cloud DNS with the following record, but without any success:

```
*.foo.dyndns.domain.tld    CNAME   300   dyndns.domain.tld
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trial and error, I finally found the solution:

As described in the tutorial: https://github.com/dprandzioch/docker-ddns on how to set up the DNS, I just had to pass `*.foo` as the `domain` parameter.